# How to change position of window controls relative to the window size

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, resize

I have an MFC program:
[image]  But when I resize the window it gets the shape:
[image]  How can I change position of controls (not size) relative to the window size?
Do I need to write some code in WM_SIZE? What kind? Or is there any easier way?
I'm fairly new to mfc, please help me??

Edited section:
please note that I'm writing an MFC dialog based program
I don't see Dock or Anchor property here!

[image]

---

**Problem's solved.[The WndResizer class is just what I need, here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125068/MFC-C-Helper-Class-for-Window-Resizing#xx4346903xx)**

Comment: can you post the code of what you did?

Comment: Goto http://www.codeproject.com and search for "resizable dialog". There is plenty of information there.

Comment: When I want to do this, I normally get the previous state of the size in a member variable of the dialog class, and then i do calculations on OnSize method in compensation for the new size.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the best way, but what I'd probably do is handle WM_SIZE and/or WM_SIZING and then in there  use :

```
m_Button.SetWindowPos(x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

where x and y are the new co-ordinates of the top-left of where you want your button.